# Get a compatible MediaPipe hand landmarks dataset extracted from the Web instead of MediaPipe Python used in the Sign language prediction model

Tags: python, reactjs, tensorflow, opencv, mediapipe

I have a Sign language prediction system with ReactJs frontend and Python backend. I have an algorithm written in Python with MediaPipe, OpenCV and tensorflow. It uses the device camera itself and extracts the landmark data points. I'm trying to implement the camera access and landmark extraction on the front-end and send those data to the Python backend through WebSocket and get the predictions out.

I have implemented MediaPipe web in the React project and extracted the data.
I have removed camera access and landmark extraction logic from Python logic.
However, extracted data from the frontend isn't compatible with the model.

Expect help to fix this or are there any other better suggestions for this problem?

**Initial Python logic (Input part only)**

```
def image_process(image, model):
"""
Process the image and obtain sign landmarks.

Args:
    image (numpy.ndarray): The input image.
    model: The Mediapipe holistic object.

Returns:
    results: The processed results containing sign landmarks.
"""
  image.flags.writeable = False
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  results = model.process(image)
  image.flags.writeable = True
  image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
  return results

def keypoint_extraction(results):
    """
    Extract the keypoints from the sign landmarks.

    Args:
        results: The processed results containing sign landmarks.

    Returns:
        keypoints (numpy.ndarray): The extracted keypoints.
    """
    lh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.left_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.left_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(63)
    rh = np.array([[res.x, res.y, res.z] for res in results.right_hand_landmarks.landmark]).flatten() if results.right_hand_landmarks else np.zeros(63)
    keypoints = np.concatenate([lh, rh])
    return keypoints



with mp.solutions.holistic.Holistic(min_detection_confidence=0.75, min_tracking_confidence=0.75) as holistic:
    while cap.isOpened():
        _, image = cap.read()
        results = image_process(image, holistic)
        draw_landmarks(image, results)
        keypoints.append(keypoint_extraction(results))
        if len(keypoints) == 10:
            keypoints = np.array(keypoints)
            prediction = model.predict(keypoints[np.newaxis, :, :])
            keypoints = []
```

**I have changed this to**

```
def predict_from_keypoints(external_keypoints):
    # Your existing code for setup
    PATH = os.path.join('data')
    actions = np.array(os.listdir(PATH))
    model = load_model('my_model')

    sentence = []
    last_prediction = None

    # Since you mentioned that keypoints would come from an external source,
    # I'm using external_keypoints as an argument.
    keypoints = np.array(external_keypoints)
    
    reshaped_keypoints = keypoints.flatten()
    print(reshaped_keypoints, "reshaped_keypoints")
    reshaped_keypoints = reshaped_keypoints[np.newaxis, :]

    prediction = model.predict(reshaped_keypoints)

    if np.amax(prediction) > 0.9:
        if last_prediction != actions[np.argmax(prediction)]:
            sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(prediction)])
            last_prediction = actions[np.argmax(prediction)]

    if len(sentence) > 7:
        sentence = sentence[-7:]

    return ' '.join(sentence)
```

**Frontend implementation and landmark extraction code**

```
function useLogic() {
  const videoElement = useRef<any>(null);
  const hands = useRef<any>(null);
  const camera = useRef<any>(null);
  const canvasEl = useRef<any>(null);

  async function onResults(results: any) {
    if (canvasEl.current) {
      if (results.multiHandLandmarks.length) {
      }
      const ctx = canvasEl.current.getContext("2d");

      ctx.save();
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasEl.current.width, canvasEl.current.height);
      ctx.drawImage(results.image, 0, 0, maxVideoWidth, maxVideoHeight);

      if (results.multiHandLandmarks && results.multiHandedness) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.multiHandLandmarks.length; i++) {
          const landmarks = results.multiHandLandmarks[i];
          const handedness = results.multiHandedness[i].label;

          if (handedness === "Right") {
            console.log("Right hand landmarks:", landmarks);
          } else if (handedness === "Left") {
            console.log("Left hand landmarks:", landmarks);
          }
        }
      }
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }

  const loadHands = () => {
    hands.current = new Hands({
      locateFile: (file) => {
        return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/hands/${file}`;
      },
    });
    hands.current.setOptions({
      maxNumHands: 2,
      modelComplexity: 1,
      minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
      minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
    });
    hands.current.onResults(onResults);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function initCamara() {
      camera.current = new Camera(videoElement.current, {
        onFrame: async () => {
          await hands.current.send({ image: videoElement.current });
        },
        width: maxVideoWidth,
        height: maxVideoHeight,
      });
      camera.current.start();
    }

    initCamara();
    loadHands();
  }, []);
```

**Sample extracted data outputs:**
Printed and logged the data and this is a sample dataset python media pipe sends to the model

```
array([ 7.37684071e-01,  8.25579405e-01,  3.65240254e-07,  6.91287994e-01,
        7.83797979e-01, -1.57016814e-02,  6.66415095e-01,  7.04194844e-01,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00])]
```

This is what react mediapipe gives

```
[
    [
        0.17021721601486206,
        0.737122654914856,
        3.98695419789874e-7
    ],
    [
        0.22619208693504333,
        0.7177075743675232,
        -0.023756584152579308
    ],
]
```